Why I'm getting two error messages on screen flow which is used in Vf page?
I have created a screen flow which is having 3 input fields which I made required from screen flow it self those fields are not required on field level and this flow has used in VF  page which will invoke by clicking on button. basically it should show only one error message for required fields but it is showing two messages. I have attached image for reference and highlighted the messages which is coming extra.
Anyone can help me to remove the extra messages.
image for reference
Wanted to remove the extra messages coming on screen flow for the required fields.
